# Is a binary tree named for the rate at which the node count increases?

Tags: tree

It occurred to me that since binary trees consist of nodes with two branches:

1. The rate at which the node count increases is exp2 (is that the correct terminology?)
2. That every node has a 'binary' choice of branches to follow.

I am relatively new to the idea of trees in general, not having studied computer science, but I've always assumed that binary trees were named for the maximum number of branches that a node can have.

Is that correct?

It seems that identifying the rate of growth of nodes is a far more useful way of classifying trees... in my very, very limited experience :p

Why is being able to constrain the rate at which node count increases in terms of the depth of a tree useful?

Comment: Binary means 2 in this case, each node can have at most 2 children. Nothing more.

Comment: And node count would increase by 1 each time you add a value not present in the tree, I don't understand what you mean in this regard.

Comment: I mean that at level 1 there is one node, level 2 there are 2, l3 there are 4 nodes, l4 8 nodes, etc. So the number of nodes at a level is related to the level in the tree you are. And for a binary tree that relationship is lg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "binary" here is a reflection of the "at most two children" property of binary trees.

Nothing more.

Nothing less.